# Can we modify the transfer syntax UID tag of a DICOM image?

Tags: dicom

While importing MRI image sets in Varian Eclipse Planning System, 
Error occured: Objects conversion unsupported 'Transfer Syntax UID' (0002,0010) 'JPEG Lossless Hier 14

Comment: I just noticed you applied python tags. Your question has nothing to do with python.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse (and other Aria apps) will not import compressed DICOM. Changing the tag alone, isn't enough. You need to decompress the image before importing. This can be done with GDCM.

http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcmconv.html

```
gdcmconv --raw compressed.dcm uncompressed.dcm
```